# I cant get UIScrollView and UIAccelerometer to play nice, even with threading

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiscrollview, uiaccelerometer

problem is, everytime i go into my application and scroll around inside the scrollview, everything else in the program is completely useless, and tills I stops me scrolling, the accelerometer, and not to mention everything else wont do a thing, if anyone has any idea how  i can get around said problem, id be much obliged, yes I would. and i tried putting them on different threads in all sorts of ways, but that wasnt worth a thing. i dunno maybe I'd been doing it wrong is all. anyway any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the rest of your main application logic is running in a different run loop mode (probably NSRunLoopCommonModes) than the UIScrollView touch handling.  If you're using any timers to control your logic, those will block until UI tracking has finished.

This fixed a problem that I had where none of my game logic was updating while the user was manipulating a scroll view.  My fix was as simple as adding the following line when setting up a timer:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

For more information, see this thread: [NSTimer not firing when runloop is blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995825/nstimer-not-firing-when-runloop-is-blocked).