# NSTimer periodic task doesn't get called while scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, nstimer

I have an NSTimer

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(periodicTimer) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
```

which does

```
- (void)periodicTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Bang!");
    if (timerStart != nil)
        [timerLabel setText:[[NSDate date] timeDifference:timerStart]];        
}
```

The problem is that while scrolling a tableview (or doing other tasks) the label doesn't get updated, furthermore, "Bang!" doesn't appear, so I supposed the method doesn't get called.

My question is how to update the label periodically even when the user is playing around with the app interface.

Comment: is the code shown in `periodicTimer` above really all that happens periodically?  you just need to update a label that displays a time?  or is there more involved background processing?

Comment: It is all that happens periodically (NSLog was just a test to see if the method at least gets called)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to add your timer to the UITrackingRunLoopMode to make sure your timer also fires during scrolling.

```
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997018/474896

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to handle this problem.  I started prototyping my solutions before the poster replied that his periodicTimer function was not a simplification for the sake of asking the question, but that he truly didn't have anything going on besides changing a text label.  So, no need to use background work as the UI update is all there is.  +1

Comment: FYI - NSRunLoopCommonModes includes UITrackRunLoopMode as of iOS 7

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about this one, but my first guess would be that the main thread on which the interface is being rendered your timer just doesn't get a chance to do anything while its updating the interface.

You could create a new thread with a new run loop for your timer, but that is a bit of an ugly solution maybe. What functionality in your app are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can advise a better strategy than using a timer.

Comment: The functionality is the timer itself. I think it's a problem about NSTimer not being called while the main thread is taking care of the UI scrolling.