# iOS NSTimer not calling selector - not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(setCurrentTime:)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [timer fire];

}
-(void)setCurrentTime{
    NSLog(@"TEST");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        [currentTime setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
    });
}
```

But nothing get called.

Comment: you typed `setCurrentTime:` but signature for this method is only `setCurrentTime` without colon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the *wrong* selector.  Your "`setCurrentTime`" implementation doesn't take any parameter (e.g. to be properly messaged or called, you should use "`selector:@selector(setCurrentTime)`".

Now, if you look at [Apple's documentation for `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWitTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a), Apple says your method should have this signature:

```
- (void)setCurrentTime: (NSTimer *) timer
```

Which means your function would look something like this:

```
-(void)setCurrentTime: (NSTimer *) timer
{
    NSLog(@"TEST");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        [currentTime setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
    });
}
```

and be called like this:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 
                   target:self 
                 selector:@selector(setCurrentTime:)  
                 userInfo:nil 
                  repeats:YES];
```

Comment: In some examples, like this one- -->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995825/nstimer-not-firing-when-runloop-is-blocked/1997018#1997018 . they have the colon. why?

Comment: Because timer call method which takes one parameter.

Comment: Isn't it better to add the `NSTimer` argument to `setCurrentTime` so the signature is correct and it's what NSTimer expects?

Comment: but if my NSTimer just updates the current time why would it need the NSTimer

Comment: @stackplasm Apple's documentation says what kind of *method signature* the NSTimer creation methods are looking to work with.  They expect a "`NSTimer *`" parameter, and if you wanted to pass along useful information to your method, you could use the NSTimer object's ["`userInfo`" dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/userInfo) to do that.

Comment: @stackplasm It's passed to the "trigger" method so it could stop the timer if it wanted.  I don't understand what you mean by "NSTimer just updates the current time" though.  Nothing inside a computer "updates time" and telling you what does is well beyond my comprehension.